# CloudKit Dashboard: Deploy Schema to Production fails with "There was a problem loading the environment’s status"

Tags: icloud, cloudkit

Note: This is not new, but I have some new insights on it.

For about three weeks now I regularly try to deploy the development-schema of my CloudKit Container to production, using the CloudKit Dashboard:

[image]

It spins for *exactly* a minute to then tell me "There was a problem loading the environment's status"

[image]

---

This is not new, many other questions face this as well:

- [Error CloudKit Dashboard - There was a problem loading the environment's status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630259/error-cloudkit-dashboard-there-was-a-problem-loading-the-environments-status)
- [Does iCloud need to be in the Production environment in order to use in Production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879420/does-icloud-need-to-be-in-the-production-environment-in-order-to-use-in-producti)
- [iCloud dashboard: Cannot deploy CloudKit schema to Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62855311/icloud-dashboard-cannot-deploy-cloudkit-schema-to-production)

Apple support told me to

- look at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656723 (try again after a day with stable network)
- use Safari and resetting browser settings to clear cache and cookies
- "You may also try creating a new CloudKit container, rebuilding your schema, and then try again." => obviously doesn't work, because users have data on production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### TL;DR:

Kill the timeout by running this in the console:

```js
var id = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 0);

while (id--) {
    window.clearTimeout(id); // will do nothing if no timeout with id is present
}
```

(the response is `undefined` — that's okay)

---

##### How I got there

So I started to look at the requests the site makes to the backend when I click "deploy". Chrome shows that the request to

```
https://p39-ckdatabasews.icloud.apple.com/r/v3/user/<container-name>/production/public/admin/deployment/status?team_id=<team-id>
```

is cancelled after 1.0 min.

[image]

##### Insight 1

The problem is with the *production* schema. I had used the `Reset Development Environment` before to make sure I hadn't messed that up myself, but this would have spared me that.

---

I used the `Copy as cURL` command (in Chrome, because it also copies the auth cookies, which Safari does not) and ran it in `Terminal`.

Interestingly, that *does* respond after 1'37 min. That's also what the `X-Apple-Edge-Response-Time: 97244` header says.

[image]

If you know what to look for, the console will also tell you the the request timed out:

[image]

##### Insight 2

The server takes too long to respond (> 1min) and the client script times out (at 1 min)

*Note:* You can also get a response by right-clicking the request in Chrome and choosing "Replay XHR".

---

##### Solution

I tried to understand the JavaScript that sends the XHR request and modify the timeout, but I failed. However, you can apparently clear *all* timeouts that exist with

```js
var id = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 0);

while (id--) {
    window.clearTimeout(id); // will do nothing if no timeout with id is present
}
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860203)

Running that while waiting for the response actually worked for me!